# trying to send user data to mongodb via angularjs and node

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

hey everyone so i have this template and i am trying to create a backend for it starting with the registration form. although there is some type of connection between my mongodb and my app, data isnt being sent to the database,
 this is the html:

```
    <ion-view class="auth-view" cache-view="false">
  <ion-nav-bar class="view-navigation">
    <ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-bar>
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <div class="row form-heading">
      <div class="col">
        <h1 class="form-title">Create your account</h1>
        <h3 class="form-sub-title">Sign up with Social Network or Email</h3>
        <div class="social-sign-up button-bar">
          <a class="button icon ion-social-facebook button-positive"></a>
          <a class="button icon ion-social-twitter button-calm"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row form-separator">
      <hr class="separator-line"/>
      <span class="separator-mark">OR</span>
      <hr class="separator-line"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row form-wrapper">
      <div class="col">
        <form name="signup_form" class="" novalidate>
          <div class="form-fields-outer list list-inset">
            <div class="row multi-inputs">
              <div class="col">
                <label class="item item-input">
                  <input class="multi-input" type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" ng-model="user.name" required>
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <label class="item item-input">
                  <input class="multi-input" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" ng-model="user.userName" required>
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <label class="item item-input">
              <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" ng-model="user.email" required>
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
              <input type="tel" placeholder="Phone Number" name="phone" ng-model="user.phone" required>
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input" show-hide-container>
              <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" ng-model="user.password" required show-hide-input>
            </label>
            <button type="submit" class="sign-up button button-block" ng-click="doSignUp()" ng-disabled="signup_form.$invalid">
              Sign Up
            </button>
            <p ng-show="error" class="message error">{{error}}</p>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

here is the code i tried in attempt to post the data

```
.controller('CreateAccountCtrl',['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.doSignUp = function(){
        console.log("doing sign up");
    $http.post('/accounts', $scope.user).success(function (user) {
        console.log(user);
        });
//      $state.go('app.feed');
    };
}])
```

and finally my server.js so far

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('accounts',['accounts']);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/www"));
// app.get('/accounts', function(req, res){
// //    res.send("i got the request")

//     db.accounts.find(function(err, docs){
//        console.log(docs);
//        res.json(docs);
//    });

// });

app.post('/accounts', function(req, res){
//    console.log(req.body.user);
    db.accounts.insert(req.body.user, function(err, doc){
        res.json(doc);
    });
});


app.listen(3000);
console.log("server running on port 3000");
```

i know there is a few things wrong but i just dont know what as i am still learning. thanks in advance for your help

i have also encountered this error from mongo

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
at /Users/beast/node_modules/mongojs/lib/collection.js:83:19
at /Users/beast/node_modules/mongojs/lib/collection.js:20:7
at apply (/Users/beast/node_modules/thunky/index.js:16:28)
at /Users/beast/node_modules/thunky/index.js:20:25
at /Users/beast/node_modules/mongojs/lib/database.js:36:9
at /Users/beast/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:519:11
at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
```

Comment: Are you getting something here ? - `console.log(req.body.user);`

Comment: no, the server crashes instantly but if i remove the .user, when i click sign up, it creates empty strings containing just an id @swapnesh

Answer (score 0):

Your express controller is looking for a property in the body called "user". Your are just passing the user object straight into the body. In your angular controller try the following:

```
.controller('CreateAccountCtrl',['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.doSignUp = function(){
        console.log("doing sign up");
    $http.post('/accounts', { user: $scope.user}).success(function (user) {
        console.log(user);
        });
//      $state.go('app.feed');
    };
}])
```